# Integrating a contact form into a fancy box

Tags: javascript, html, forms, lightbox

Could somebody please advise me of the best way to have a working contact form within a fancy box? This is how far I have got but I am running into trouble with every attempt I try.

```
<div class="clearfix">

  <div class="cul apear floatL">

    <div class="verticalLine"></div>

    <figure class="diamond relative"> <a class="fancybox" href="img/diamond01.jpg"><img class="centerAbsolute" src="img/diamond01.jpg" alt="Free plumbing quote"></a></figure>

    <h2 class="proximaBold">Get A Free Quote <br>

      Right Here, Right Now</h2>

    <div class="line"></div>

    <p>We offer free quotes so you can see the value for money that we guarantee. <br>
```

Comment: I made this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/LD7Zm/)** for custom login modal but you can use it for the any content. Clean & simple no need for Fancy ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you consider using an iFrame for this? Give this code a try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#iframe" ).fancybox({
            'width'             : '50%',
            'height'            : '50%',
            'autoScale'         : false,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none',
            'type'              : 'iframe',
            'href'              : "http://www.yourhost.com/form.php"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, the onky thing is I have more than one fancy box on the page so will this effect all of the fancy boxes? Thanks

Comment: you define which form to display by assigning it to certain div-container or <a> or whatever. Just specify this (`$("#iframe" ).fancybox({`) Should work also if you got multiple fancyboxes on your page.

Comment: so I replace the "#iframe" with the div id I want it to load in?

Comment: for example if your div looks like this `<div id="test"></div>` you have to call `$("#test").fancybox({...` if you want to open the Fancybox with a link you can use this `<a href="#" id="test">LINK</a>`